# I want to invoke firestore functions locally

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I don't know how to execute below code locally.

```
export const dataFunc = functions.firestore.document('data1/{data1Id}/data2/{data2Id}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
  var newValue = snap.data();
});
```

Invoke: dataFunc('new_data', {auth: {uid: '***'}})

Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.

Comment: Are you sure that `data1, data1Id, data2 and data2Id` are not empty?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes. I get the error only locally. I want to know the command locally